# Andrdoid, Parse.com: Same Parse Query SOMETIMES returning nothing

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm querying my database on Parse.com and sometimes the query returns an empty list and other times it actually grabs the data I wanted. 
I can't fathom why running the exact same query on a database that hasn't changed is sometimes returning the results I want and other times nothing.

Here's an example of the query I'm running:

```
ParseQuery<Answer> answerParseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Answer");
    answerParseQuery.whereEqualTo(Constants.kQollegeAnswerQuestionKey, curQuestion);
    answerParseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Answer>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Answer> list, ParseException e) {
            options.addAll(list);
        }
    });
```

I've made sure that everytime I run it the curQuestion is the same.

What could possibly be going on that sometimes the list returned is empty and other times the list contains the parse Objects I wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `find()` instead of `findInBackground()` as it runs in Asynchronous background Thread it returns empty List Some times and Others times it wont.

```
ParseQuery<Answer> answerParseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Answer");
    answerParseQuery.whereEqualTo(Constants.kQollegeAnswerQuestionKey, curQuestion);
    answerParseQuery.find(new FindCallback<Answer>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Answer> list, ParseException e) {
            options.addAll(list);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think thats the issue, because anything I was doing was inside the done function.
I set a breakpoint inside done as well and was seeing that the list size was 0 sometimes.
I'll try and report back

Comment: But your Accessing options List outside 'done()' function,Which is on Main Thread

Comment: Acutally, I'm not. I just put that for the sake of the example. Everything I had to do with the list was done inside the done block

Comment: Changing to find instead of findInBackground didn't solve anything... still only sometimes is finding results.